# Rails repeatable partials rendering boost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates

There are matherials, some of them have about 300 comments and more. All comments need to be dispalyed without pager.

i am rendering them this way:

```
<% comments.each do |comment|%>
    <%= render "comments/comment", :comment => comment, :attachment => (attachment ||= false) %>
<% end %>
```

but it takes 2.2 sec to return page in production env.

```
Completed 200 OK in 2624ms (Views: 2255.9ms | ActiveRecord: 79.4ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

(working on rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2)

Is there a method to speed up rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually measured that the rendering of partial is inducing so much overhead?

Why do you assume that it's not the general view code that has to be rendered (and the volume of code) that slows the application down?

The simplest solution here would be to simply not use a partial but rather duplicate the code and test again.

You could also look into [output caching or fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: It is not a problem of using partials. I did move code from partial template to the main, but it didn't affect rendering time

Comment: @houston are you using caching at all?